# youtube play button on right to left browser language

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

the play button is centered when I use google chrome in English, when I change the language of the browser to Hebrew (right to left) and also drag Hebrew to the top of the languages list, the play button is not centered, it has a bit offset.

I tried to set the html, body and the iframe of the embedded player with direction:ltr, but I didn't helped.

if I open the f12 developer tools and locate the play button and then change it's position from left 50% to right 50% it fixes the problem.

but that can only be done via the developer tools and not from javascrit/css.

I think that the css class of the button should be adapted to the browser's language.

does anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Thank you.